# How to override the default database of my Active Directory group

Tags: sql-server, windows

We have a database server running SQL Server 2008 and we connect using Windows authentication based on Active Directory group membership.  The group that gives me my login rights has the default database set to Abel, and that is how other members of the group like to have it. I want my default database to be Baker.  Back when I had my own SQL Server login, I knew how to change its defaults.  Can I still change my default database under Windows group authentication in away that will affect only me, and not the other members of my group?

Comment: In brief: NO. If you authenticate by means of the AD group login, then that group login has one and only one default database that applies to **ALL** members of the group.

Comment: @marc_s: thanks, that makes sense.  If you could submit that in the form of an Answer, I would Accept it.

Comment: Updated my response with this comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the SQL Server's `Security` node in Object Explorer (inside SQL Server Management Studio), find your AD group's login, and change that group's "default database" property to whatever you want it to be:

[image]

**Update:** in response to your comment: no, you cannot have a different default database than your AD group's login defines. If you authenticate by means of the AD group login, then that group login has one and only one default database that applies to ALL members of the group

Comment: Thanks, but I need to clarify that my group has other members, and I don't want to inconvenience them.  I'll go edit my question.

Comment: @Narveson: if you authenticate by means of your AD group, you have exactly one default database for all members of the group. You cannot have a separate default database for yourself while the others in the group still have another database. Sorry, just doesn't work that way...

Comment: @Narveson: not sure if you could create a specific SQL login for your own user, and then define a different default database on that login. You'd have to try. If you can't do that, I don't see how you'd be able to get what you're looking for, sorry.